# ROS2 - Rviz2 connect to ros instance?

Tags: ros2, rviz

is it possible to rviz to the robot through network ?

I used to do this from a ubuntu VM to a rpi but I had to install a master and a slave

now I am really talking about installing Qt graphical tools and connect to the robot via network

how can I do that ? the only example I found is via ssh

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! What you're describing is another example of a multi-machine setup, which is described in the official documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Domain-ID.html).

To provide more detail, you need to make sure that

- Your robot and your laptop can communicate with each other over the network. The easiest way to confirm this is with the `ping` command.
- Both the robot and the laptop have the `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` environment variable set to the same value.

To do this you'll need to be able to run commands on your robot, because that environment variable needs to be set on the robot in the same environment that you launch your ROS 2 configurations with. The `ssh` command is the most popular way to do that, but if you interact with your robot using a keyboard+monitor you could do it that way instead.

Comment: yet I dont understand how to tell rviz to communicate to the robot. should I provide the ip as a parameter ? the laptop is NOT part of the robot

Comment: ROS 2 has auto-discovery, so you don't really need to do anything on the ROS side. ROS 2 on all machines that share a common ROS_DOMAIN_ID will just be able to communicate. However, firewalls and other network configuration issues could potentially interfere, so if it doesn't just work, look in that direction.